# How to solve blank white page screen of my WordPress multisite?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, multisite, domain-mapping

I have created a WordPress multi-site.
The main site is [accordingtotommy.com](http://accordingtotommy.com/) and I added a site in subdomain which is `atripthroughtime.accordingtotommy.com`.

`atripthroughtime....` works well but when I installed the [WordPress MU Domain Mapping](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-mu-domain-mapping/) plugin for mapping my subdomain site into a new domain [atripthroughtime.com](http://atripthroughtime.com/) then it redirects there perfectly but shows a blank page.

Please tell me how to solve this problem.

Comment: In the config file change debuggin to true define('wp_debug',true); and then look for errors

Comment: Same result.Again its showing white blank page. accordingtotommy.com , atripthroughtime.accordingtotommy.com and atripthroughtime.com all domain are located in same directory.Is this causing the problem?

Comment: What about the .htaccess.

Comment: Dear Jan Doggen ,
What do you mean by "general cleanup" ?